# Is there a way to change vba range declarations based on user input?

Tags: vba, variables, range

I have built an auto grading utility for the school I work for. I am working to build the various versions of our tests. I wanted to know if instead of writing new functions for each question pointing to specific ranges in my answer key, I could have the first portion of the range declaration change based on a drop down from my GUI sheet. example below

```
Function q1(i as range) as Integer
''''For each ans in range.("Sheet2!A2:A3").cells 

'is there a way to make the Sheet2! portion a variable that I can change based on user input???

''''''''if (userinput.Value = ans.Value) then

''''''''''''j = j + 1 and so on
```

I would hope that the user could pick version 1 and the value of my variable would change to "Sheet2!A2:A3" (I only want the Sheet2! portion to change, not the cell references)

Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: You can do this with a `Select Case`, or a bunch of other ways really

Comment: You don't normally include the `"Sheet2!"` part in the address string, because you qualify `Range` with a `Worksheet` object - e.g. `mySheet.Range("A2:A3")`. Use logic to determine what worksheet object to use - keeping `Range` unqualified and parameterizing it with a sheet name in the address string is asking for trouble IMO.

Comment: If you received a valid answer, please mark it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many values will be available in your drop down you have, `Select Case` may be a clean way to assign user input to some sheet. If you have a lot, this option becomes less flattering.

I'm assuming that `Sheet("Sheet?").Range("A1")` is where the value of your drop down box will be. You can also have this fire automatically when that cell changes, but idk if that is applicable here

---

```
Sub Jeeped()

Dim Version As String
Dim Bank As String

Version = Sheet("Sheet?").Range("A1")

Select Case Version
    Case "Version 1"
        Bank = "Sheet1"
    Case "Version 2"
        Bank = "Sheet2"
    Case "Version 3"
        Bank = "Sheet3"
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
End Select

For Each Ans In Sheets(Bank).Range("A2:A3")
    '......
    '......
Next Ans

End Sub
```

*I can also see an array of versions mapped to arrays working here as well as a simple `VLOOKUP`*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.InputBox()` to ask the user to select a range:

```
Dim r As Range, ws as worksheet
Set r = Application.InputBox("Pls select a range", , , , , , , 8)
Set ws = r.Parent
```